# Expanding a Source object in a Stripe API call to StripeBalenceService doesn't return any customer info

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I'm making a c# call to the [Stripe.net API](https://stripe.com/docs/api) to fetch a [balance history](https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_history) for a connected account. I'm trying to [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api#expanding_objects) on the [balance transaction object](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Entities/StripeBalanceTransaction.cs) to see where the charge is coming from (ex. the customer who made the charge) as all the charges to connected accounts on my platform are from [charge objects with a destination property to the connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

Here is my code and a screenshot of what the expanded source looks like, but think I should see a charge id or a customer or something refering me to the initial customer somewhere, but I don't...

```js
var balanceService = new StripeBalanceService();
balanceService.ExpandSource = true;
var list = new List <string> () {
  "data.source.source_transfer"
};
StripeList <StripeBalanceTransaction> balanceTransactions 
  = balanceService.List(
  new StripeBalanceTransactionListOptions() {
      Limit = 20,
      Type = "payment",
      Expand = list
  },
  new StripeRequestOptions() {
    StripeConnectAccountId = accountId
  }
);

foreach(var transaction in balanceTransactions) {
  var test = transaction;
}
```

[image]

I feel like I should see a charge id (ex. ch_xxx) or a Customer value (which is null) all I see of any relevance is a payment id (ex. py_xxx)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the charge object(`ch_xxx`), it is just a little involved!

As you are using destination charges, the charge(`ch_xxx`) takes place on the platform account, and then a [transfer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfers)(`tr_xxx`) is made to the connected account. That transfer creates a payment(`py_xxx`) on the connected account, which results in a balance transaction(`txn_xxx`).

As your code expands the source of those balance transactions, you get the payment(`py_xxx`). The payment is equivalent to a charge, so it has a [`source_transfer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-source_transfer) field. You can expand this field also! This will give you the transfer object(`tr_xxx`). Finally, the transfer has a [`source_transaction`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfer_object-source_transaction) field, and this can be exapanded to give the original charge(`ch_xxx`)!

Putting that all together, you will want to expand on `"data.source.source_transfer.source_transaction"`.

If you use a Stripe library in a dynamic language you can see this in action ... unfortunately, `stripe-dotnet` has an [open issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/1162) right now which means that you can not do this directly. Instead, you will need to make the API calls manually by calling the various `Retrieve` functions on the IDs, instead of doing a single expansion. It would look something like this:

```
var paymentId = transaction.Source.Id;
var chargeService = new StripeChargeService();
var payment = chargeService.Get(
    paymentId,
    new StripeRequestOptions()
    {
        StripeConnectAccountId = accountId
    }
);
var transferService = new StripeTransferService();
transferService.ExpandSourceTransaction = true;
var transfer = transferService.Get(payment.SourceTransferId);
var charge = transfer.SourceTransaction;
Console.WriteLine(charge.Id);
```

Comment: Hi Karlekko. It looks as if the 'balanceTransactions' from my post has a 'ResponseJson' object in it that contains the charge object ids (ch_xxx). Would using this json object and pulling the ids out of this be easier or will I run into problems later on?

Comment: Oh, that's a good catch. That should be fine — that field is the [`source_transaction`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfer_object-source_transaction) of the expanded `source_transfer`, so it's the same thing, and it's part of the API definition so you can rely on it.

Comment: Hi Karlekko. Looking at it again, the json object has a bunch of '\n' characters in it! Is this typical or something Stripe has done intentionally? And does Stripe have a way to read that ResponseObject into a Stripe object that might handle the '\n' removal or cleanup?

Comment: Yes, it's normal, and Stripe parses that JSON string into the `StripeList<StripeBalanceTransaction>` objects. The problem is that, due to the [issue](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/issues/1162) I mentioned earlier, the `source` field of the JSON response is not being parsed to the correct type of object, so you can't access all the fields of that object as you should be able to. You can either parse the JSON yourself, or use the code I posted(that relies on the `source`'s ID, which is parsed correctly) to get the information with more API calls. I know it's not ideal.

Comment: It just seems like if I want to use the JSON object data I would have to do some manual cleanup of the '\n' first, is that accurate to say? I would much rather use the JSON data if I don't have to make additional API calls, which would save me time/money in the long run. What would you recommend?

Comment: Sure, using the JSON data has advantages over calling the API multiple times. I'm not massively familiar with C#, but I would think most JSON parsers should ignore newline characters like that, or can be configured to do so. In the long run, stripe-dotnet will eventually be fixed so you don't have to do this. In the meantime, parsing the JSON is fine, the format shouldn't change, it's defined in the API version that you're using.

Comment: Where is everybody getting all of this information on implementing the Stripe API in C#? I've been starting to implement it using Stripe.Net and running into a couple of issues when e.g. defining a Charge object class, which, unfortunitly, has a property named "object". Can't very well do that in C#.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question with your specific question/difficulty.